# How to send many form input values with $.ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a form with many input elements inside that looks like:

```
<form>
  <input name="foo[abc]" />
  <input name="foo[def]" />
  ...
</form>
```

(foo should be a array inside $_POST)

How can I send these values trough AJAX, without having to manually enter each value in the data parameter?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the serialize function; see an example [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) (it's a `$.post()`, but same difference).

Answer (score 3):

use:

```
var data=$(your_form).serialize();
```

and send this `data` using ajax.

it'll automatically convert all array like inputs and normal to a string like get method..

Answer (score 1):

```
$("form").serialize();
```