# Pass many input values through ajax

Tags: ajax, input

My question is related to this [How to send many form input values with $.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380489/how-to-send-many-form-input-values-with-ajax)

Want to understand how to pass ~ 100 input values through ajax

For example input

```
<input type="text" name="your_form[]" id="amount1">
<input type="text" name="your_form[]" id="amount2">
<input type="text" name="your_form[]" id="amount3">
```

And ajax is like this?

```
var data=$(your_form).serialize();

$.ajax( {
type: "POST",
url: "php_file.php",
data: {"data" : data},
cache: false,
```

Please, advice

Comment: serialize() is the best method

Comment: In my opinion,It is the best method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass all your input fields like this:

```
<form id="my-form">
    <input type="text" name="your_form[]" id="amount1">
    <input type="text" name="your_form[]" id="amount2">
    <input type="text" name="your_form[]" id="amount3">
    ...
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$.post("php_file.php", $("#my-form").serializeArray(),
    function(data){
        [handle response here]
    }
);
```

Comment: And if without array (Use only name="your_form1", name="your_form2", name="your_form3") then instead of $("#my-form").serializeArray() I must use $("#my-form").serialize()?

Comment: the `serializeArray()` is not used because we have the attribute name as an array, it only will encode a set of form elements as an array of names and values and the `serialize()` will encode a set of form elements as a string for submission. See [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)